# Code that batch renames all .png files with increasing numbers, but how to i add so that the same happens with .jpg files too?

Tags: powershell, batch, batch-rename

Workflow:

use **`cd FilePath\Folder`** first
write **`ls`** to get the files read
code that works with **`.png`** files only:

```
Get-ChildItem *.png | 
   ForEach-Object -Begin { $count = 1 } -Process { 
   Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$count.png"; $count++}
```

Comment: Use a separate `Get-ChildItem` for `*.jpg`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry i am not very good at writing or understanding new code. Nor good at asking the questions the right way. I have a folder with a lot of .jpg and .png files. That i wan't to rename so they all have increasing numbers from 1. 

I found that this code:
Get-ChildItem *.png | ForEach-Object -Begin { $count = 1 } -Process { Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$count.png"; $count++ }

works with only .png files

What code snippet do i need to add, or what code, specifically do i need to write, for this to work, in a way that adds .jpg files to be renamed together with the .png files.
Use powershell

Comment: Given files: `a.jpg`, `b.png`, `c.jpg`,  and`d.png`, are you wanting: `1.jpg`, `2.png`, `3.jog`,  and`4.png` OR `1.jpg`, `1.png`, `2.jpg`,  and`2.png`?

Answer (score 0):

To get common numeration for files with extensions `.png` and `.jpg`:

```
$ext = '.png','.jpg'
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Extension -in $ext} | ForEach-Object -Begin { $count = 1 } -Process { Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$count.png"; $count++ }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ran it a few times to see. This did number all the files, so it worked. But it seems to order it in a way I did not expect. The files seem mixed up somehow. 
The error it says: Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
The files i have, have numbers already, with 3 to 4 characters some xxx, some 0xxx. fx 324 and 0325. Maybe this is the cause. They are all in the order I want them to be in, but need new numbers. maybe there is an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: @JonasHelt, You can start from any arbitrary number: change `-Begin { $count = 1 }` to `-Begin { $count = 10000 }`. **BUT remeber**: this script will rename **all** files in your folder with `.png` or `.jpg`. If you want so save some of them - move them to another location.

Comment: @JonasHelt, regarding order: you could add something like `Sort -Descending |` before `ForEach-Object`. Read more on [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/sorting-objects?view=powershell-7.3)

Answer (score 0):

```bat
$count=[int] 1
Set-Location 'C:\FilePath'

Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.jpg,.\*.png | 
    Foreach { Rename-Item $_.FullName -new $((Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 $_.FullName).Hash+$_.Name) }

Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.jpg,.\*.png | Foreach { if ($count -ieq (Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.jpg).count) {
    $count=[int] 1 } else { $count++ } ; $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}{1}' -f $count,$_.Extension) }
```

---

- Considering the scenario described in the comment below... I suggest you double-name your files avoiding renaming duplicate files in the final/permanent action...

> *Thank you for your answer. Ran it a few times to see. This did number*
> *all the files, so it worked. But it seems to order it in a way I did not*
> *expect. The files seem mixed up somehow. The error it says:*
> *`Rename-Item :`*
> *`Cannot create a file when that file already exists`.*
> *The files i have, have numbers already, with 3 to 4 characters some xxx,*
> *some 0xxx. fx 324 and 0325. Maybe this is the cause. They are all in the*
> *order I want them to be in, but need new numbers. maybe there is an easier*
> *way to achieve this?*

---

Note that the error points to the need to apply a pre-treatment before the action of permanently renaming.

What I would suggest is that you first rename it so that there are no duplicate names for the respective new destination names for your files.

This can be done in such a way that each file is renamed to a name layout that contains *Some_Odd/Unique_String + The_Current_Name_of_The_File + .File_Extension*

```bat
Rename-Item $_.FullName -new $((Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 $_.FullName).Hash+$_.Name)
```

---

**Obs.:** When using `Get-Childitem *.jpg,another extension`,the first `eXtension` should be used in the forward complement where the relevant eXtension is counted to get the count value for numerical reset to be used in the second extension. Otherwise the counter will reset without the relevant extension being in the last file.
Forgive my limited English, I hope you understand, if in doubt, do not change this `eXtension` order:

```bat
*.jpg,*.png | .. | . {.. ($count -eq (Get-ChildItem *.jpg).count) ..
```